# Ubuntu 18.04 - Can't install sysv-rc-conf package for managing startup services

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, xubuntu, sysv

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

I am not able to install sysv-rc package. Tried to install from deb package but there are so many dependencies that I failed by downloading them one by one.

Why sysv-rc package is not anymore supported in ubuntu 18?
I tried also apt-get install rcconf, but it is not found anymore too.

Is there any alternative for sysv-rc-conf or maybe a solution to install this package in ubuntu 18?

Comment: This seems like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You seem to be asking about changing init (which is an unwise course of action) instead of asking about the real problem you are trying to solve. If you wish to manage startup services, then use systemd targets - it is not difficult.

Answer (score 2):

SysV was replaced by systemd.

You can get some background information why in this article for example https://fossbytes.com/systemd-vs-sys-v-vs-upstart/

And here is a cheatsheet to get you started with systemd https://www.2daygeek.com/sysvinit-vs-systemd-cheatsheet-systemctl-command-usage/#

Comment: Useful fact:Systemd became the Ubuntu init in 2015.

Comment: Yes, it surprises people who migrate from 14.04 which was last LTS without systemd

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who used to have the `sysv-rc-conf` (Debian family distros) or `ntsysv` (Red Hat family distros), there is another alternative compatible also with systemd. You can use the serman2 tool from the archlinux repository. It's a small program written in python and does the job similarly. Just [download it](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/serman), uncompress and copy the script into your `/usr/local/bin` directory. Eventually, in some distros you may have a problem to find the `systemctl`, which can be easily solved with a symbolic link with the command below:

```bsh
wget -c http://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/serman/src/serman-2014.7.tar.xz
tar xvf serman-2014.7.tar.xz
sudo cp serman-2014.7/serman2 /usr/local/bin
# in some distros the sysctl is located under the /bin directory
ln -s /bin/systemctl /usr/bin/systemctl
```

There you go, now you just execute the `serman2` command in your shell