# restore default startup service in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, startup, settings, default

I used `sysv-rc-conf` to close some startup service. But after that my ubuntu virtual machine could not boot successfully. I use recovery mode to boot. Now I want to restore default startup service settings. I'm not sure which service must be on, and which can be switched off. How can I restore default settings?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's Ubuntu 20.04? Why are you using ancient, unsupported software on Ubuntu 20.04 (see this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106216/ubuntu-18-04-cant-install-sysv-rc-conf-package-for-managing-startup-services))? SysV was replaced by `systemd` 6 years ago. 

Comment: Yes, it's ubuntu 20.04. A tutorial on how to set startup service told me that,  so I installed it.

Comment: That must be a very old tutorial then.

Comment: there did you get this program I canot found in ubuntu 20.04. remove it. Maybe this will do it identify all programs that use /etc/init.d/  `dpkg -S /etc/init.d/` and reinstall them and also package init-system-helpers