# E : Unable to locate package sysv-rc-conf

Tags: 22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I tried to install sysv-rc-conf but the package is unable to locate. how can I fix it?

E : Unable to locate package sysv-rc-conf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 - Can't install sysv-rc-conf package for managing startup services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106216/ubuntu-18-04-cant-install-sysv-rc-conf-package-for-managing-startup-services)